# ¿ Se puede aplicar el patrón MVVM con objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm

¿ Es posible construir código MVVM con objective-c ? Es decir que la vista refresque los datos que cambian del modelo automáticamente.

Comment: Observando el modelo. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html

Comment: Gracias.. ¿ Sabes de algún enlace donde este explicado en español ?

Answer (score 1):

Existe ReactiveCocoa, que permite binding. Es un proyecto basado en ReactiveSwift que a la vez se basó en ReactiveUI.

Lo tienes en github: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres implementar una arquitectura para Objective-c te puedo recomendar usar VIPER, si bien puedes utilizar ReactiveCocoa el problema es precisamente que tienes que utilizar una librería externa para que pueda funcionar.

El pro de VIPER es que vas a poder isolar todas tus funcionalidades
El contra es que a veces tienes que crear muchas clases

En lo personas prefiero utilizar algo más seguro que yo lo construya y pueda tener el control y evitar problemas futuros

Queda mas o menos así las carpetas en base a 
View: Solo se encarga de la vista y hace más como un receptor de clicks.

Interactor: Podría representarse como el controlador, maneja la logica que tienes en view

Presenter: Es el que se encarga de mostrar las vistas y hace de comunicación entre el view y el interactor

Entity: Todos los modelos que utiliza el Interactor

Router: Es el que redirecciona y se encarga principalmente de la navegación

Al final te dejo un link para más detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://medium.com/cr8resume/viper-architecture-for-ios-project-with-simple-demo-example-7a07321dbd29

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación. Tienes algún enlace de documentación practica que lo explique en español ?

Comment: Lo único que he encontrado de VIPER gratis en español, te puedo recomendar este link https://apiumhub.com/es/tech-blog-barcelona/arquitectura-viper/